# Specialize a template for void parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I have a the following template and specialization (this code is not correct, but hopefully demonstrates my intent well enough):

```
template <typename T> widget &&make_widget(T &&val) { // (1)
    return std::move(widget(std::forward<T>(val)));
}

template <> widget &&make_widget(void) { // (2)
    return std::move(widget());
}
```

The intent is to have a factory function that can be called like this:

```
make_widget(arbitrary_function());
```

And have it choose the default constructor if `arbitrary_function` returns `void`.

However, with clang 3.7 I get the following error:

```
error: no function template matches function template specialization 'make_widget'
```

pointing to the line of (2). How can I implement this correctly?

Comment: "if arbitrary_function returns void" then it can't be used as an argument

Comment: `make_widget(void)` doesn't mean taking a `void` parameter, but means taking *no* parameter.

Comment: The problem is not the declaration of make_widget(), but the function call make_widget(arbitrary_function()), which attempts to pass a void type to a function call parameter. gcc's error message in this case is more informative: "error: invalid use of void expression"

Comment: also, returning an rvalue reference to `std::move(widget(std::forward<T>(val)));` is UB

Comment: and even if it weren't UB, it still wouldn't be desired, as it prevents RVO. Just return by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this. It's impossible to create a function that has a parameter of type `void`. What you can do is make the function variadic, like `make_unique`.

```
template <typename... T>
widget make_widget(T&&... val) {
    return widget(std::forward<T>(val)...);
}
```

Then if you want to do something like

```
auto w = make_widget(void_function());
```

there is nothing stopping you from just doing instead:

```
void_function();
auto w = make_widget();
```

or even, if you really need it to be one statement for some reason,

```
auto w = (void_function(), make_widget());
```

Three further notes:

- You should nix the `std::move` in the return statement since the result of calling the constructor is already an rvalue.
- Never return a reference (even rvalue reference) to a temporary! It will always become a dangling reference.
- There is no point to the `make_widget` function if forwarding its arguments to the `widget` constructor is the **only** thing it does. Note that `make_unique` takes care of calling `new` for you, and that `make_tuple` deduces the template arguments for the `tuple` itself. Your `make_widget` function doesn't do anything like that.

Comment: (std::move mistake aside) I can't do what you suggest because make_widget is called from a generic function where `arbitrary_function` may have a void return type. Does this mean that the only way out is specializing the caller function?

Comment: @TamásSzelei There is no way that you can make `make_widget(void_function())` work if `void_function` really returns `void`. Maybe some sort of evil macro hack, but I don't know what that would look like.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki `arbitrary_function` is a function template whose return type depends on a template argument.

Comment: @TamásSzelei how can it be a function template, if it takes no arguments in your example? as it's currently written, it can't be solved, but if you post the actual code, then I believe there does exist a solution to your problem

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki the function that calls make_widget takes `arbitrary_function` as an argument. In other words, its arguments are specified elsewhere.

Comment: @TamásSzelei so, clearly, you can dispatch the call depending on what `arbitrary_function` (passed as an argument) returns. that's why you should post the actual code that depicts your design

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki you are right, I just tried to present a minimal example. Clearly this question requires more context. I will edit it when I get the chance.

Answer (score 1):

As it's been pointed out, the problem is not really in the template specialization, but the usage of a void expression.

I can, however, suggest an alternative syntax that uses an intermediate lambda, and a helper template, to achieve the same results at a cost of a little bit of negligible extra usage syntax.

```
#include <functional>

class widget {

public:

    widget();
    widget(int);
};


template <typename T> widget &&do_make_widget(T &&val) { // (1)
    return std::move(widget(std::forward<T>(val)));
}

widget &&do_make_widget() { // (2)
    return std::move(widget());
}

template <typename T>
class do_make_widget_invoke {

public:

    template<typename functor_type>
    static auto invoke(functor_type &&functor)
    {
        return do_make_widget(functor());
    }
};

template <>
class do_make_widget_invoke<void> {

public:

    template<typename functor_type>
    static auto invoke(functor_type &&functor)
    {
        functor();
        return do_make_widget();
    }
};

template<typename functor_type>
auto make_widget(functor_type &&functor)
{
    return do_make_widget_invoke<decltype(functor())>
        ::invoke(std::forward<functor_type>(functor));
}
```

Testing the above with g++ 5.1.1 in -std=c++14 mode, I seem to get the right results with the following syntax, which is pretty much what you're trying to accomplish:

```
int foobar()
{
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    make_widget([]{ return foobar(); });
}
```

and:

```
void foobar()
{
}


int main()
{
    make_widget([]{ return foobar(); });
}
```

Comment: don't `return std::move(widget(std::forward<T>(val)));`, especially if the return type is `widget&&`

Comment: This part is simply copied from the original question, as is.